# Want Word Document object, but code defaults to DAO Document object

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, dao

I’m working in Outlook and automating Word (2010).

Having a problem as code is defaulting to the Document object for DAO, but I want to use the Document object for Word (both applications have a "Document" object - but is not the same object).

When I set the Dim for the Document object I am presented with two "Document" options, regardless of which one I choose the result in the code is the DAO Document object with its members.

Example

```
Dim objDoc as Document <--------- Intellisense shows two "Document" Options

objDoc. <------------- Intellisense shows only DAO members (AllPermissions etc)
```

I do have a reference set for the DAO 3.6 Object Library in Word as I use it in other macros (not in this one) so I don’t want to remove this Library. I have run one of these macros which should close the database and set it to nothing - but did not fix the problem.

Also tried opening and closing the db in the subject code as below.

```
Dim db As DAO.DataBase
Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\...........')
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
```

How do I get the code to default to the normal Word Document Object.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the code is defaulting to the DAO option" ?  What problem are you seeing ?  Show the code you're writing and where the problem shows up.

Comment: I have edited the question, hopefully clearer now.

Comment: `Dim objDoc as Word.Document`

Comment: Thanks, technically the answer below came in a minute sooner so accepted that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the library for `Document`, and I would do so for both rather than assuming that DAO will always be the default:

```
Dim d As DAO.Document
'        ^^^^
Debug.Print d.UserName

Dim e As Word.Document
'        ^^^^^
e.AcceptAllRevisions
```

When I do this, with the references set, the Intellisense suggestions are different for `d` than for `e`.

The Intellisense suggestions and the object library references happen before your code is running.  As a result, you will get the same suggestions regardless of whether you have a database or a Word document open.  Just in case you haven't, at the beginning of every source file, add

```
Option Explicit
```

This will cause the compiler to give you errors when you try to use undeclared variables, which may help with your debugging.